# Is there a way to not return any result to client in case of errors raised using RAISEERROR?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm using Entity Framework to call SP. My SP in successful run gives back a string, so I have set up my return type as string in EF mapping. When executed it works fine and I'm able to get the result.

In case of errors, there is a code in SP that returns error information as a table. As I've set up string as my SP return type in EF, I get error whenever I get error row as result.

To get over with this issue, rather than sending error rows, I started using RAISEERROR(...) and catch the exception in C# code.

There are few SPs that internally calls other SPs which still return error row. So in case of failure now, I get a error result from internal SP and a raise error from outer SP. Again this causes failure in C# code because of return type mismatch. Surprisingly, exception is also ignored by .Net.

Is there a way in SQL or EF where I can ignore all results for a batch in case of error?

This is how I raise error

```
RAISERROR ('%s <%s:%d:%s>', 16, -1, @ErrorMessageText, @inProcName, @inErrorID, @EventLogGUID)
```

SP name is ABC, it is added to EF and called by C# code as a simple DBContext function. It should throw error and I don't have try catch block.

Comment: Please show your C# code. Do you have try/catch blocks in your C# code? Can you also show your RAISEERROR code too, RAISEERROR must use  a severity greater than 10 in order for it to be caught in C#. Try using 16 as the severity level as this is the most common for general errors.

Comment: You can try/catch in the procedure